# Import path is different when service is deployed to AWS lambda using serverless framework

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

When I deploy a serverless function to AWS I get "Cannot find module '../knexfile'". That import path works when im working using serverless-offline. However, when I deploy to AWS all the packages get included at the root level so the import path is not correct. When I change it to 'knexfile' instead of '../knexfile' it works when deployed but not when ran locally. What can I do for the path to be what it needs to be automatically?

I would like for the path to get automatically resolved when deployed to AWS or tested locally.

Comment: You need to verify if the module is included in the deployment package...

Comment: I specified in the question 'when I deploy to AWS all the packages get included at the root level'. I was able to solve my problem using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I used the serverless-webpack npm package to solve the problem. This ended up being my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development': 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
  externals: [nodeExternals(),
    {
      'sqlite3': 'sqlite3',
      'mariasql': 'mariasql',
      'mssql': 'mssql',
      'mysql': 'mysql',
      'mysql2': 'mysql2',
      'mssql/package.json': 'mssql/package.json',
      'mssql/lib/base': 'mssql/lib/base',
      'oracle': 'oracle',
      'strong-oracle': 'strong-oracle',
      'oracledb': 'oracledb',
      'pg-native': 'pg-native',
      'pg-query-stream': 'pg-query-stream',
      'tedious': 'tedious'
    }],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
  }
}
```